# Scaling font as window is resized

Tags: c++, fonts, wxwidgets

I'm writing a C++ calculator application in wxWidgets.

[image: My application]

I want the font of all the buttons and the two wxTextCtrl's to be scaled as I resize the window. How is that done? I'm posting some code if that can help.

**text_controls.cpp**

```cpp
#include "main.h"

void Main::AddTextControls()
{
    //creazione font
    wxFont Expression(10, wxFONTFAMILY_SWISS, wxFONTSTYLE_NORMAL, wxFONTWEIGHT_LIGHT, false, "Lato");
    wxFont Main(30, wxFONTFAMILY_SWISS, wxFONTSTYLE_NORMAL, wxFONTWEIGHT_LIGHT, false, "Lato");

    wxBoxSizer* sizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);

    ExpText = new wxTextCtrl(this, wxID_ANY, "", wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxTE_READONLY | wxNO_BORDER);
    ExpText->SetFont(Expression);
    ExpText->SetForegroundColour(wxColour(125, 125, 125));
    sizer->Add(ExpText, 1, wxEXPAND);

    MainText = new wxTextCtrl(this, wxID_ANY, "", wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxTE_READONLY | wxNO_BORDER);
    MainText->SetFont(Main);
    MainText->SetForegroundColour(wxColour(55, 55, 55));
    MainText->Bind(wxEVT_TEXT, &Main::OnTextChange, this);
    sizer->Add(MainText, 2, wxEXPAND);

    MainSizer->Add(sizer, 4, wxEXPAND);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [wxFont::SetPixelSize()](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1/classwx_font.html#a94f364735647de9ddd065dfa992ad4e4) to set the font size to, say, one third of the text control height. E.g.:

```cpp
MainText->Bind(wxEVT_SIZE, [this](wxSizeEvent& e) {
    e.Skip();
    MainText->SetFont(wxFontInfo(wxSize(0, MainText->GetSize().y / 3)).Family(wxFONTFAMILY_SWISS).FaceName("Lato").Light());
});
```

(which also shows using a more readable way of creating a `wxFont` than the ctor taking a zillion arguments).

Comment: [I tried pasting this code into mine](https://pasteboard.co/K4z5cMv.png), and it gives all sorts of errors. [E1730] Member "Main::MainText" is not a variable  [E1738] Cannot reference the container function "this" in the body of a lambda expression unless it is included in the capture list [E0135] class "wxFontInfo" doesn't include any "Facename" member  (I don't know if I translated correctly, I'm using Italian Visual Studio).

Comment: I didn't realize `MainText` was a member variable, you need to capture `this` in this case. I've also made a typo in `FaceName`, sorry. I've updated the answer now, but in any case, it was meant more as an illustrative example rather than something to be used as is.

Comment: It worked, although I needed to change the wxFontInfo size from wxSize to int, because it was causing problems. Thank you so much!

Comment: If you use int size, it gives the size in points which is not the same as the size in pixels, notably when using high DPI (i.e. display scaling > 1).

Comment: But if I use wxSize(-1, MainText->GetSize().y / 3) as you said the text is glitched and unreadable.

Comment: Which version of wxWidgets do you see this with?

Comment: I don't know how to check this, but it should be development release 3.1.5

Comment: In 3.1.5 using pixel size for fonts should definitely work. If it doesn't work for you, please try reproducing it in a simple example and opening a bug on wxTrac.

Comment: It's the -1 giving problems. If I change the number to about 10, it looks fine.

Comment: Hmm, sorry, maybe you should use 0 instead, I'll update the answer.

Comment: Thanks, it works now. But there are two problems: 1. Font size is updated when I maximize the window, but not when I minimize it, making it cover like half of the screen until I resize the window 2. I applied this method to some  custom buttons but [I'm not being able to precisely display the text on the center of the button](https://pasteboard.co/K4Mhiwn.png) (note especially the green and red ones, the other have their text slightly higher than they should). [Here's the code.](https://pasteboard.co/K4Mgwo7.png)